# PHP mssql count rows in a statement

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I would like to count the number of rows in a statement returned by a query. The only solutions I found were:

1. **sqlsrv_num_rows()** This one seems a bit too complicated for such a simple task like this and I read that using this slows down the execution quite a bit
2. **Executing a query with SELECT COUNT** This method seems unnecessary, also it slows down the execution and if you already have a statement why bother with another query.
3. **Counting the rows while generating a table** As I have to generate a html table from the statemnt I could put a variable in the table generating loop and increment it by one, but this one only works when you already have to loop through the entire statement.

Am I missing some fundamental function and/or knowledge or is there no simpler way?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

**EDIT:** The statement returned is only a small portion of the original table so it wouldn't be practical to execute another query for this purpose.

Comment: Could you provide the link that says `sqlsrv_num_rows` slows down? Also, in my opinion, using `sqlsrv_num_rows` takes same effort as using `select @@rowcount` if you want both results and count, because you have to use `sqlsrv_next_result` and then `sqlsrv_fetch` (maybe more effort) to get the count.

Comment: @alalp Mainly here: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php) but I have gone with this (sqlsrv_num_rows()) method and it is quite fast even with close to 200 000 rows.

Comment: Seems that cursor type is the main reason for performance. I simply tested (used microtime) `sqlsrv_num_rows` on a real-time used table. In 100 times loop, I called a query, which returns appr. 150 rows. There is no significant time difference between `sqlsrv_num_rows` and incrementing a counter in `while` loop with `sqlsrv_fetch()`. However, it may differ on very busy servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql server table rows information is stored in the catalog views and Dynamic Management Views you can use it to find the count

This method will only work for the physical tables. So you can store the records in one temp table and drop it later

```
SELECT Sum(p.rows) 
FROM   sys.partitions AS p 
       INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t 
               ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id] 
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
               ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
WHERE  p.index_id IN ( 0, 1 ) -- heap or clustered index 
       AND t.NAME = N'tablename' 
       AND s.NAME = N'dbo';
```

For more info check this [***article***](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way)

If you don't want to execute another query then use `select @@rowcount` after the query. It will get the `count` of rows returned by previous `select` query

```
select * from query_you_want_to_find_count 
select @@rowcount
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but I'm looking for a way to count the rows of a returned statemnt, not execute another query for this purpose

Comment: @gergalyb - then use `select @@rowcount` after the query

Comment: hmmm, select @@rowcount for me returns 4 while my returned statement is huge

Comment: @gergalyb Make sure you run the `select @@rowcount` query right next to the select query for which you need to find the count

Comment: By right next do you mean immediately fter or within one query? (I ran it after it) @fireblade

Comment: @gergalyb - added an example

Comment: Sadly this is still not working for me, but I will figure it out. Thank you so much for your effort, I wish I could give you more rep :)